# How can I use the internal macOS firewall to redirect localhost requests from to an external device on my nework?

Tags: networking, macos

I have a web server running on an Arduino board. It connects to my Mac's internet sharing and is accessible on `192.168.2.2:80`.

I want to be able to access it when requesting a certain localhost port on my Mac.

How can I use `fpctl` to redirect requests from this localhost port to my board? For the moment I have `rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {5050} -> 192.168.2.2 port 80` but I think I am missing something to pass through the internet sharing layer, and it has something to do with `bridge100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a SSH tunnel...

1. get SSH service up and running  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237038/os-x-terminal-command-to-turn-on-off-ssh-server
2. open a terminal and run the command `ssh -L5050:192.168.2.2:80 yourusername@localhost`  - note that your username is your Mac login name/username on your desktop/laptop you are working on.  Replace `5050` and `80` with appropriate port numbers - `5050` is the port you want to connect to, `80` is the port your traffic from `5050` should be fowarded to.

   What this does is it opens a listening port on your localhost, that goes through the SSH tunnel and from the end point (still your local machine) to whatever that host sees as `192.168.2.2` on that remote machines port 80.  This means that if you set up your home router to allow you to SSH to your Mac, you can use the exact same command and connect to your board from anywhere on the internet....
3. open a browser to `http://localhost:5050`  - you should see whatever the page normally serves up

   When you do this, even from some remote location, the machine you are forwarding a port to will always see the IP of the machine you SSH into as the source address for the connection.  If you use a host name instead of an IP as your target for the port forward, you will be pointing to whatever machine the SSH host resolves that name to.

Comment: It worked ! And it is way more simple than with `pfctl`. But just out of curiosity, why use ssh tunneling over pfctl ? Is there any reason other than simplicity here ?

Comment: @ypicard simplicity and even more importantly both cross platform and can tunnel any TCP based connection as long as there is a network path between the SSH server/host and both the client and the end point.  Note that no direct path from client to end point is needed - the tunnel does that for you. Works on Mac, Linux, BSDs, Windows machines, anything.  The SSH client I use for my iPhone supports tunneling.  All you need is a SSH server that isn't configured to NOT allow tunneling, and a SSH client that supports it.